# How can I query data from Google Analytics and display it on my website?

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a .NET web application for which I want to query some Google Analytics data and then display it in my own dashboard on the website. I am new to this and I could not find recent documentation or examples that work.

Has anyone succeeded in querying and displaying Google Analytics data with C#?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: There is a library for this: https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples